NeoVim Treesitter RST highlight for Python docstrings
I'm trying to configure treesitter to apply rst highlight group to docstrings in Python.
In after/queries/python/highlights.scm I set the following:
(module . (expression_statement (string (string_content) @comment)))

That works, but if I set it to rst:
(module . (expression_statement (string (string_content) @rst)))

It goes back to highlighting docstrings the same as normal strings.
rst is in checkhealth nvim-treesitter:
Parser/Features         H L F I J
...
 - rst                  ✓ ✓ . . ✓
...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

I found what I needed, injections go in queries/python/injections.scm, not after/queries/python/highlights.scm, and are done like so:
;; extends

; function/method docstring
(function_definition
  body: (block .
    (expression_statement
      (string
        (string_content) @injection.content (#set! injection.language "rst")
      )
    )
  )
)

; module docstring
(module .
  (expression_statement
    (string
      (string_content) @injection.content (#set! injection.language "rst")
    )
  )
)

